# How does the try, except, else, and finally blocks work in Python, and what is their purpose in exception handling?

Tags: python

How does the try, except, else, and finally blocks work in Python, and what is their purpose in exception handling?
try:

except ExceptionType:

explain how to write else, blocks work in Python, and describe the purpose in exception handling

Answer (score 1):

Here is an application of exception handling, when you want to divide two numbers taken from the user, if the second number is zero it will result in a zero division error so you can apply exception handling to prevent to error from stopping the program.

```
try:
        num1 = int(input("num1: "))
        num2 = int(input("num2: "))
        num3 = num1 / num2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Please enter non zero value for num2")
    else:
        print(num3)
        print("try successful")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

the above blocks are used to handle instances when there might be an error in your code, you write your code in the try block and the except block is executed when there might be a specific error in your code e.g. an arithmetic error (dividing a number by zero) so if there are no errors in your code, the except block is skipped. the finally block is executed regardless of the errors.